# Creat a loop to generate a a mean value of data which I got form TXT files?

Tags: matlab, text, for-loop

I trying to do script to evalute my lab data into matlab, I have lots of txt files for many samples, each sample has 30 txt files. I did a function to get the data from these files and store them into a structure that contains data and labels. 
I would like to know if it is possible to load all the 30 files using loop instead of line by line .

```
function s = try1(fn)
    % adapt for other file format according to your needs
    fid = fopen(fn);
    s.data = [];
    % skip first lines

    for k=1:6
        l = fgetl(fid);
        % read header
        a = regexp(l,',','split');
        s.labels = a;
        l = fgetl(fid);
        k=0;
    end

    while( (l~=-1)&(k<130) )
        l = l(1:end-1);
        a = regexp(l,', ','split');
        a = regexpre
        p(a, ',','.');
        s.data = [s.data; str2double(a(2:4))];
        l = fgetl(fid);
        k = k+1;
    end
    fclose(fid);
end
```

Comment: I assume you could call `try1` inside a loop - or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes but I want to give the folder destination of txt files  and this loop get all the files inside this try1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you want with a  data directory and processing each file in a loop you can use a combination of `fullfile(...)` and a loop. This will likely work:

```
dataDirectory = 'c:/myDirectory';
allFilesDir = dir(fullfile(dataDirectory , '*.txt'));
allFN = {allFilesDir.name}

% Or do this:
% allFN = {'file1.txt', 'file2.txt'};

result = [];

for ind = 1:length(allFN)

    myFN = fullfile(dataDirectory, allFN{ind});
    result(ind) = try1(myFN);

end

% Now get the mean:
myMean = mean([result.data])
```

Comment: This is a good wwaz but i got this message 'The following error occurred converting from struct to double:
Error using ==> double
Conversion to double from struct is not possible.'

Comment: ?? The following error occurred converting from struct to double:
Error using ==> double
Conversion to double from struct is not possible.
 
      Error in ==> getmean at 13
      result(ind) = try1(myFN);

Comment: I think in this case i have to change my try1 function to able to use it for fullfile(....) @Steve

Comment: to be more clear . Now with function try1 . I got like this when I call it :   data: [100x3 double] and some labels .  I need to just to use these data . to get the mean value of them

Comment: @mecaeng Full file just takes a directory and filename and combines them appropriately (usually by adding a `/` or `\` depending on the OS... or _not_ if there already is one present).

Comment: @mecaeng if the structure is giving you grief you might try saying `result=try1(...)` and then do `myMean=mean(result.data)` to get a 3 means of 100 values,`myMean=mean(result.data')` to get 100 means of 3 values, or `myMean=mean(result.data(:))` to get a mean of all the values in the 100x3 block.

Comment: I went to 3D array option then squeeze my results, seems it's going to work in this way.    (:,:,n)